# Photo Thumbnails on Ubuntu

Tags: printing, 17.04

When I was running Ubuntu 14.04 I could print photos on my Canon MX926 as good, if not better than from a commercial photo shop.  Since installing Ubuntu 17.04 prints produced are unacceptably very dark and dull.  I am not proficient in computer technology so would appreciate if you could tell me in simple detail how I can again produce top quality prints from my printer.  Thanks ....Jim Fraser

Comment: Did you already installed your printer drivers? Have you configured your printer options, normally there are options to get better results with photos? Did you check your printer cartridges, old cartridges or empty can cause worse results...